# why use @Url.Content

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Can someone please explain why I should use (or should I?):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/SomeScript.js")"></script>
```

vs

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/SomeScript.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The fragment `@Url.Content("/Scripts/SomeScript.js")` does absolutely nothing, and is equivalent to just `/Scripts/SomeScript.js`.

However, for paths starting with "~", it will translate the url to the correct, application relative url, e.g., `@Url.Content("~/Scripts/SomeScript.js")` could translate to `/MyVirtualDirectory/Scripts/SomeScript.js`, if you deployed your web application to a virtual directory MyVirtualDirectory below the root folder of the web site.

Comment: +1, With other words: `Url.Content` makes sure that all links works no matter if the site is in a virtual directory or in the web site root.

Comment: Just an additional note: `Url.Content` it's been a great help so far, but in MVC4/Razor2.0 it's no longer needed, we can now use: `src="~/Scripts/SomeScript.js"`.

Comment: Also, because the default `type` is `text/javascript` it's OK to leave it out. This is OK for all current, and even old, browsers.